# issues with md-virtual-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

We are having some IE11 performance issues on an app that's using Angular Material.  I looked into it and apparently this is well known, and started to look at solutions.  One of which was replacing large `ng-repeat` lists with a `md-virtual-repeat` directive.  I've tried this and have mixed results.  It boils down to a few issues:

1. I can't see the items unless I dynamically remove the `md-virtual-repeat-container md-orient-vertical` class from the `md-virtual-repeat-container`.
2. I have multiple tabs on the page (it is a shopping page sorted by category, with a list under each tab) and the elements are only repeated if I click a tab, then click off, and re-click.
3. The height of the div with the class `md-virtual-repeat-sizer` is absurdly high (~2000px and up to 48000px for larger lists).

At first I thought that it was related to being nested inside of another `ng-repeat`, but I'm not sure that's the culprit.  Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
<ng-form name="vmProduct.productsForm" novalidate>
<div ng-repeat="InventoryItemSubCategory in vmProduct.products | filter: ($scope.selectedGroup !== 'All' || '') && $scope.selectedGroup | filter:$scope.query | groupBy:'InventoryItemSubCategory':'productsByCategory'">
<h2>{{InventoryItemSubCategory.InventoryItemSubCategory}}</h2>
<md-content ng-cloak="">
  <md-virtual-repeat-container id="productRepeat">
    <div md-virtual-repeat="product in InventoryItemSubCategory.items">
      <md-card class="product-card" md-theme="default" md-theme-watch>
        <md-card-content>
        </md-card-content>
      </md-card>
    </div>
  </md-virtual-repeat-container>
</md-content>
</div>
</ng-form>
```

My other thought that it was due to using `md-card` directives instead of `div` elements but I'm not sure.

Has anyone run into this before?  Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should always use `track by` with large data sets in `ng-repeat`. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat - Provide a codepen or something, otherwise no one can really help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @kuhnroyal.  It's a little tough to make a codepen for my particular situation.  I implemented a `track-by $index` based on your suggestion.  However, the more I look into it I think the performance issues are related to the filters I use in Angular and the way they destroy/recreate the DOM instead of hiding/showing it.  I'm going to look a little bit more into that as a potential solution.  Thanks again!